# return object length which includes key is true not false

Tags: javascript

I want to write some filter logic where an object returns its length which includes only key having true value.

```
     $scope.generated.codesWithBalance = [A:true, B:true, C:false];
```

so for above object it should return length as 2. Since C is false so want to exclude in the count.

But now whenever i try to get the length it returns total length

```
    Object.keys($scope.generated.codesWithBalance).length
```

Any way that i can avoid key having false value?

Comment: `[]` is used for arrays. Objects use `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get only the keys with true values.

```
Object.keys($scope.generated.codesWithBalance).filter(function(key, i, array) {
    return array[key];
}).length;
```